# How to update view via function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, scope, digest

In the following example, I wrote a function that works fine by the default value of $scope.word but when I update the view or input, its not updating the $scope in controller so that its not reflecting back to view. not sure how data binding and digest cycle here works. Thanks,

html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" ng-model="word"></textarea>
    <br>
    {{word}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">{{key}} : {{value}}</li>
    </ul>
    <dir text="largetext"></dir>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.obj = {}
    $scope.word = "d a c a d a b c b b c b d d";
    var str = $scope.word.trim().replace(/[\.\,\']/g,"").split(" ");
    function wordCount(str) { 
        var _obj = {}
        str.forEach(function(word){
            (word in _obj) ? _obj[word]++ : _obj[word] = 1
        })
        return _obj;
    }
    $scope.wordCount = wordCount;
    console.log($scope.wordCount(str));
    $scope.obj = wordCount(str); 

}])
```

[here is jsfiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/7r83qbh8/1/)

Comment: You fiddle is woking fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code::

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" ng-model="word" ng-change="wordCount()"></textarea>
    <br>
    {{word}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">{{key}} : {{value}}</li>
    </ul>
    <dir text="largetext"></dir>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.obj = {}
    $scope.word = "d a c a d a b c b b c b d d";
    function wordCount() { 
    var str = $scope.word.trim().replace(/[\.\,\']/g,"").split(" ");
        $scope.obj = {}
        str.forEach(function(word){
            (word in $scope.obj) ? $scope.obj[word]++ : $scope.obj[word] = 1
        })
        return $scope.obj;
    }
    $scope.wordCount = wordCount;
    console.log($scope.wordCount());
    $scope.obj = wordCount(); 
}])
```

Comment: thanks for answer. why did you declared $scope.obj again in the wordCount function?

Comment: no, i have not declared.. i have assign empty object... so that count of chars should be current on... else it will go to ++ lastly counted chars as well..

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7r83qbh8/2/)

Demo code

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" ng-change="wordCount(word)" ng-model="word"></textarea>
    <br>
    {{word}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in obj">{{key}} : {{value}}</li>
    </ul>
    <dir text="largetext"></dir>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.obj = {}
    $scope.word = "d a c a d a b c b b c b d d";

    $scope.wordCount = function(str) { 
  str = str.trim().replace(/[\.\,\']/g,"").split(" ");
        $scope.obj = {}
        str.forEach(function(word){
            (word in $scope.obj) ? $scope.obj[word]++ : $scope.obj[word] = 1
        })    
    }       
  $scope.wordCount($scope.word);
}])
```